# Hide empty rows on an individual column basis

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report to show children in different houses. However, currently, the report has empty rows, as each child appears on a new row.

Currently:

[image]

I'd like it to look like the following if possible:

[image]

Please could someone point me in the right direction, if this is possible.

Comment: We'll need some more information to figure this out.  What does the design view of the report look like?  Could you also provide an idea of what the data looks like in SQL Server?

Comment: The report looks like this in design view: https://i.ibb.co/5hTb46B/report-design.png

Comment: `SELECT        txtSurname, txtForename, txtAcademicHouse, intNCYear, txtForm
FROM            TblPupilManagementPupils
WHERE        (intSystemStatus = 1)`

Comment: Have you added any grouping logic to the table?  It seems like you could get the results you need by grouping by `[txtForm]`, though it may be more complex than that... It could also be something you need to add to the query, such as `GROUP BY txtForm, txtAcademicHouse, intNCYear, txtSurname, txtForename`.

Comment: I currently group by '[txtform]' so that each class is separated. However, I still get each child appearing on a separate row.

Comment: The query that you posted seems to be different from the one you used for your dataset. What do you expect to see when multiple children are in the same house (and class)?

Comment: Basically, at the minute, each child's name sits on a separate row, so when you've got loads of names there are lots of empty cells. I'd like it so that all the names come one after the other in the column, obviously separated by class. so more than one name can be in a row, is this possible?

Comment: Group the Class group by Class. Use MAX(Fields!House1.Value) to eliminate the nulls. This **ass**u**me**s that you only have one non-null record in any Class.